# Installing older version of php5-postgresql using Macports

Tags: php, postgresql, macports

The latest php and postgresql releases supported by Macports are:

```
php5-postgresql                @5.3.10_0
postgresql91                   @9.1.3_0
postgresql91-server            @9.1.3_0
```

However, for compatibility reasons, I need to install the following versions:

```
php5-postgresql                @5.3.8_0
postgresql91                   @9.1.1_0
postgresql91-server            @9.1.1_0
```

Here's the command I tried:

```
sudo port install php5-postgresql @5.3.8_0+postgresql91 @9.1.1_0
```

... but this just installs 9.1.3 all over again.

How can I get Macports to install the versions I need?
Thx!

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe you can get specific version numbers after the `@` sign.

However, you may be able to get older versions of postgresql by doing something like for example:

```
postgresql84
postgresql84-server
```

You may want to check the mac ports site.

Here is a source on how to install postgres using mac ports however:

http://iosdeveloperforums.com/f23/installing-postgresql-osx-using-macports-52.html